# Calculating the variance I get infinity

Tags: java, arrays, variance

I have create a method to calculate the variance but, well lets just say that I have a logic error. Instead of getting the variance I get output as Infinity.

See output:

```
============ DataSet Test ================================
10 Data Items
[5.55, 47.9, 21.27, 6.59, 42.96, 74.3, 99.17, 50.99, 77.36, 62.76]
Minimum: 5.55 at index 0
Maximum: 99.17 at index 6
Data Range: 93.62
Median    : 56.875
Mean      : 48.885000000000005
Variance  : Infinity
Std Dev   : 0.0
```

And here is the code:

```
  //Return the variance of the points in this DataSet   
   public double variance()
   {
  double[] meanVar = this.data;

  for (int k = 0; k < meanVar.length; k++)
  {
  meanVar[k] = meanVar[k] - mean();
  meanVar[k] = Math.pow(meanVar[k],2.0);      
  }

  double variance = 0.0;

  for (int k = 0; k < meanVar.length; k++)
  variance = variance + meanVar[k];

  variance = variance / size();

  return variance;
 }
```

Comment: Check the value of `size()` and try to find why this value is equals to `0`.

Comment: I checked, the value of size is the same as the length of the data array. Just to check I changed it to variance = variance / meanVar.length;  and still get the infinity error.

Comment: Well that means that the length of your array is 0.

Answer (score 1):

What is `size()` right before the `return` in the `variance()` method?

Perhaps you mean `meanVar.length` there.

Comment: I still get infinity if i change it to meanVar.length

Comment: @Jason091 You will really learn how to debug your program then. Just print all the variables out at every step (`if`, `else`, `for`-iteration, etc.). Then you can actually see what is going now, because for now it will be just guessing.